# How to make child elements equally share an ancestor's(not parent) 100% width?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="ancestor1">
    <div class="ancestor2">
        <div class="ancestor3">
            <ul>
                <li>List Item 1</li>
                <li>List Item 2</li>
                <li>List Item 3</li>
                <li>....
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ancestor 1 is for some reason set to `width: 100%` of it's parent element and it must remain like that. I want the list items to ignore the widths of ancestors 2 & 3 and equally share ancestor 1's width with equal padding between them. The list items must cover the width of ancestor 1 with padding included. You may suggest altering the width of ancestor 2 and 3 in order to achieve the effect but not ancestor 1. Ancestor 1 must have width set to 100%.

Comment: so where is your CSS?

Comment: the css is basically `all: initial`

Comment: that does not work like that. You should show what you tried and others can help you find an error / solution

Comment: Hold on, I will edit.

Comment: I just realised that this is a "how" type of question not "what is wrong".

Comment: what I can or my css can do for the `<li>` is dependent mostly on `<ul>`. I'm asking how to change that fact and make `<li>` take from ancestor 1. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, that you able to use the flexbox to solve your problem. You can read [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to find the other examples of using this nice approach. But I should notice, that this approach has one disadvantage, it is not complete supported by the [old browsers](http://caniuse.com/flexbox).

The solution is presented below:

HTML:

```
<div class="ancestor1">
    <div class="ancestor2">
        <div class="ancestor3">
            <ul>
                <li>List Item 1</li>
                <li>List Item 2</li>
                <li>List Item 3</li>
                <li>....
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ancestor1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.ancestor1 ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}

.ancestor1 ul > li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y3ob5Ldk/1/